# Webpage for MDT

Tags: mdt

I have setup MDT server and is working fine. Every time we need to login to the server then open deployment workbench, then add computer name & asset tag details to run the deployment.

I want to know how can I setup a web page, where the link is opened and key in the required details and run the deployment.

[image]

Guide me how to set this page.

Comment: Why not just select the deployment type on the client computer itself? If that is in the cards then I have some solutions for you.

Comment: On the client side, i don't like to do any action, reason, when deploying computers more than 10 systems it will addon work. so i need to key in all details in webpage.computername, type of os to deploy.

Comment: Ok, so do you key in the details on the computer itself or from a central consle?

Comment: I have setup the database, A new computer with computername/serial number  and role is choosen to sechedule the deployment. On the client computer side press F12 choose the type of  litetouch 86 or 64 then key in the username & password, then installation starts and completes.

Answer (score 1):

Front end web page created and linked to the MDT Database. From the webpage able to key in the details and start the OS Deployment.